# Question closed as a duplicate although it isn't

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080843/can-i-parse-json-either-into-a-string-or-another-concrete-type-as-object) has been closed for being a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432166/how-to-deserialize-a-json-property-that-can-be-two-different-data-types-using-js), where it isn't.

The original question is all about deserializing different values from JSON into a **concrete type** and mine about deserializing different values from JSON into an **`object`**. Although the original question therefore doesn't provide an answer, my question has been closed.

Comment: The follow the directions you were given on that page and edit the question to clarify how the questions are different.

Comment: Which as I see has already been done, so I don't see why there is a need to post here.

Comment: It was clear long before it's been closed but apparently no one made an effort to read the actual question before voting for closing.

Comment: @t3chb0t Then apparently it wasn't as clear as you thought it was.

Comment: @Servy maybe, maybe not. It's not like the community always reads everything correctly and is always free from fault. (I can't comment on the question at hand though, due to lack of domain knowledge. It would be nice if someone could weigh in.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 By definition, if people are reading the question and are interpreting it as a completely different question, then the question is insufficiently clear.  Yes, it would be nice if people were better at interpreting questions so that making questions clear would be easier.  Sadly though, communication is hard, on both ends.

Comment: Isn't appealing a (possibly) wrongful closing on Meta what we always tell people to do? In that case voting to close as a dupe is hardly productive, no? @jon

Comment: @Servy true, but there are limits to what one *can* do to make it clear their question isn't a dupe of question x without putting "This is not a dupe!!!!!!!" in bold letters in the first line (which most of us would likely remove as noise, and possibly downvote).

Comment: And then you have people contending over whether a certain portion of a question is noise, or critical to distinguishing the question from would-be duplicates. Can't win.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GI5kwSap9Ug

Comment: @Pekka 웃: Ah, yes, on formatting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246665/why-do-people-ask-why-questions-with-the-why-capitalized-and-excessively-for

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, there are limits, but there is also a lot one can do.  For example, getting to what makes the question unique very quickly, rather than asking a question that matches a common dupe for its top 75+% of text only to add some caveat at the bottom.  Opening with what makes the situation unique, rather than burying it deep in the question, can be extremely effective at helping people realize the question isn't a dupe.  This is of course just one of many tricks to help make it clear to readers that a question isn't a dupe, rather than just stating it's not a dupe.

Comment: @Pekka 웃: Oh god, I haven't seen Astérix in forever.

Comment: @Servy that is undoubtedly true.

Comment: @BoltClock neither have I! Memories....

Comment: I think the reason for users to post about duplicates at here is they don't know the edited question will be thrown to review queue automatically. the tip box only tells me to edit the question, but not tell me how and who can reopen the question.

Comment: @amuse I admit this is exactly the reason why I posted it here. I didn't know I will be available for rewiew when I edit it. I thought no one would ever notice my changes until someone else stumbles upon it and presesses vote-for-reopen.